# Prototype with jQuery works only once

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a prototype with jQuery. I would like to execute something after window resized in using `$(window).resized()`.

```
$.fn.resized = function(callback, timeout) {
    $(this).resize(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('resizeTimeout')) {
            clearTimeout($this.data('resizeTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('resizeTimeout', setTimeout(callback, timeout));
    });
};
```

I use my prototype twice like that (examples) :

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $(window).resized(function() {
        console.log('Test 1');
    }, 300);

    $(window).resized(function() {
        console.log('Test 2');
    }, 300);
});
```

All works fine but when I use it twice. Only the second instance is executed.

So I tried to use `$.each` for each instance but without success.

```
$.fn.resized = $.each(function(callback, timeout) {
    $(this).resize(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('resizeTimeout')) {
            clearTimeout($this.data('resizeTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('resizeTimeout', setTimeout(callback, timeout));
    });
});
```

Can I have some help please ?

Comment: Using `each` won't make any difference as you're effectively doing that already.  Your issue is that you are calling it for the same object, but you're storing only *one* resizeTimeout against that object - so calling it twice you only have one resizeTimeout - the last one.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement a debounce - there are plenty of working solutions for this, so have a quick search around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And it's possible to create an variable to have multiple resizeTimeout ?